# How do I keep a malleable instance variable/list called Inv while being able to add to it in several other classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create my first project using inheritance. My expectations were to use user input as a text adventure and collect items. While class StartEnviroment only has a sword in the Inventory list. there is a choice to puck up a rock as well. It returns Inventory which was to be expected. Once the user finds the choice to move North, South, East, or West, they would Type west and the code would break due to  self.Inventory not being an attribute. But I still just want the list to be manipulated as you male the choices to pick up items.

Here is the code I've been using.

```
print("Text adventure attemp #8")

class Players:
    def __init__(self, Name, Inventory):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Inventory = Inventory

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.Name)


class Player1(Players):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Name = input("What's your name: ")
        self.Inventory = ["Sword"]

    def __str__(self):
        lirst = self.Name, self.Inventory
        return str(f"Hi {self.Name} your items {self.Inventory}")


class StartEnviroment(Player1):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Inventory = ["sword"]
        for i in self.Inventory:
            print("In a world of green, you see a small but odd rock... Would you like to pick up the rock?")
            inp = input().capitalize()
            if inp == "Y":
                print("ok")
                self.Inventory = ["sword", "Stone"]
            elif inp == "Yes":
              print("Yes")
              self.Inventory = ["sword", "Stone"]
            else:
              pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(f"your items: {self.Inventory}")


class EastEnviroment(StartEnviroment):
  def __init__(self):
    self.Inventory = (f"{self.Inventory}")
    for i in self.Inventory:
         print("You end up in a forest where you find a twisting 6in stick. Do you pick it up?")
         inp = input().capitalize()
         if inp == "Y":
             print("ok")
             self.Inventory = ["sword", "Stone","Stick"]
         elif inp == "Yes":
           print("Yes")
           self.Inventory = ["sword", "Stone","Stick"]
         else:
           pass
           
  def __str__(self):
        return str(f"your items: {self.Inventory}")


def main():
    P1 = []
    World1 = []
    Group = Player1()
    P1.append(Group)
    WorldN = StartEnviroment()
    World1.append(WorldN)

    for i in P1:
        print(WorldN)

    print("would you go North, South, East, or West? ")
    Inp = input()
    if Inp == "East":
        return EastEnviroment()
    else:
      pass

main()
```

Comment: Why do you think that it does not work? What does that mean?

Comment: As you can see with me Picking up a rock into my inventory my output shows my inventory. I want to do the same thing for my North environment sub class. I just want to add to the existing list, while keeping the answer to the earlier choice from the Start environment sub class.

Comment: Character strings can represent the content of a variable as human-readable text, but they are not the same as the actual value of that variable (e.g. `123 != '123'`). You return strings, but not usable values. Having said that, it's unclear what the actual problem here is. What are you trying to do? What outcome did you expect, and what outcome did you get?

Comment: Why is `Player1` a subclass of `Players`? It seems like it should be an instance.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `lirst` variable?

Comment: This whole thing seems to indicate a misunderstanding of how class hierarchies are supposed to be used. You're using subclasses for "has-a" relationships rather than "is-a". An environment isn't a kind of player.

Comment: I thought I deleted lirst. But to summarize, I'm teaching myself and I am confused on what I did and how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to the site, James.  It is a little beyond the scope of a normal question to do good coverage of a big topic like inheritance.  As mentioned in the other comments, there are several structural issues here that show some confusion.  Have you read any tutorials on this?  I'd recommend you start here with Think Python, which is an excellent (and free) book covering many topics.  Look at chapter 18, which defines the "is a" relationship.  https://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/index.html